# Coalesce in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have the following sql select :

```
SELECT c.id, c.code, c.closed, COALESCE( c2.name, c.name ) AS name
FROM  `centers` c
LEFT JOIN  `centers_i18n` c2 ON c2.center_id = c.id
AND c2.lang =  'ES'
```

in my zend application y have the following select:

```
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from($this->table);
    $select->join($this->multiLangTable, $this->table . '.id=' .$this->multiLangTable . '.' . $this->foreignKey, $mapping);
    $select->where($conditions);
```

It's the same but I don't know how to make a coalesce from the columns name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify columns that you want to select and add one as Expression

```
$select->columns(
  array(
    ... 
    'name' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COALESCE( c2.name, c.name )')
    ...
  )
);
```

whole code should be close to this (i haven't worked with Zend for a some time so there can be error here):

```
 $select = $sql->select();
  $select->columns([
     'id' => 'id',
     'code' => 'code',
     'closed' => 'closed',
     'name' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COALESCE( c2.name, c.name )')
  ]);
  $select->from(['c' => $this->table]);
  $select->join(['c2' => $this->multiLangTable], 'c.id = c2.' . $this->foreignKey, $mapping);
   $select->where($conditions);
```